# Why does some features of SVG path not working in Safari (with jQuery + demo)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, safari

I am playing around the SVG fill animation with jQuery. But I found something quite weird.

So I created a demo and there're 4 buttons in it. Those buttons are designed to:

1. Fill the SVG path directly. This works great in both Chrome and Safari.
2. Fill the SVG path with an animation. This works in Chrome but NOT in Safari.
3. Fill the SVG path with an animation from color A to B. This doesn't work.
4. Animate the SVG path from opacity value 0 to 1. Like #2, this works in Chrome but NOT Safari.

I did some research but still got confused a lot. Especially the different case for two browsers. What I know is that the `use xlink:href` stuff might bring the pain. But I have to use it because it's a very good way to repeatedly use the same graph to save the size. So I created this demo, hope to get some fundamental tutorial or solution to my confusion.

All the questions above are explained in the following code:

```js
var raw_svg = $('#svg_holder').html();

$('#plan1').click(function(){
 $('#svg_holder').empty().html(raw_svg);
 var $path = $('svg').find('#test').find('path');  
  $path.css('fill', '#f00');
  
});

$('#plan2').click(function(){
 var $path = $('svg').find('#test').find('path');  
  $path.css('fill', '#00f');
 $path.css('transition', '5s');
});

$('#plan3').click(function(){
 $('#svg_holder').empty().html(raw_svg);
 var $path = $('svg').find('#test').find('path');  
  $path.css('fill', '#f00');
 $path.css('transition', '5s');
  $path.css('fill', '#00f');
});

$('#plan4').click(function(){
 $('#svg_holder').empty().html(raw_svg);
 var $path = $('svg').find('#test').find('path');  
 $path.hide();
  $path.css('fill', '#f00');
  $path.show(5000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="svg_holder">


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="none" x="0px" y="0px" width="296px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 296 100">
<defs>
<g id="test">
<path fill="#669999" stroke="none" d="
M 24.85 0
Q 22.15 1.95 20.35 4.05 19.15 5.45 18.8 5.45 18.75 5.45 16.6 3.5 14.45 1.5 14.15 1.5 6.4 3 0.7 15 0.75 15.65 1.35 17.15 1.95 18.6 1.95 18.95 1.95 19.25 0.8 20.35 -0.25 21.4 0.1 22.35 0.5 23.6 3.85 23.6 8.45 23.6 13.9 24.75 14.15 24.8 15.35 23.9 17.45 22.35 19 21.35 19.65 20.95 20.8 19.2 22.3 16.9 22.8 16.25 27.45 9.95 32.75 6.5 34.9 5.1 35.3 4.6 36.2 3.7 36.2 2.25 36.2 0.9 33.9 1.05 31.3 1.55 30.6 1.65
L 24.85 0 Z"/>
</g>

</defs>

<g transform="matrix( 1, 0, 0, 1, 10.2,10.05) ">
<g transform="matrix( 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,0) ">
<use xlink:href="#test"/>
</g>
</g>

</svg>
</div>

<button id="plan1">
1 - Fill directly to #f00
</button>

<button id="plan2">
2 - Animate to #00f with CSS transition
</button>

<button id="plan3">
3 - Animate from #f00 to #00f with CSS transition
</button>

<button id="plan4">
4 - Animate from opacity 0 to 1
</button>
Questions:
<ul>
<li>
  Why does animate from 0 to 1 works in Chrome but not in Safari?
</li>
<li>
  Why doesn't "Button 2" works in Chrome but not in Safari
</li>
<li>
  Why doesn't "Button 3" not working as a transition but "Button 2" does?
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Th third one isn't working because you are not giving the browser the chance to make the path red, before you change it to blue. Put a `setTimeout()` or something in there: [See this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y84d2o16/).  I don't have access to Safari right now, so I can't help you with those questions.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau thanks. Safari is important to me because iOS takes the same result